# ProgrammingError: relation "django_site" does not exist

Tags: python, django

#### Running:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

#### fails with:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_site" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "django_site" LIMIT 1
```

I have `django.contrib.sites` included in my installed apps and `SITE_ID = 1` in my settings. I have also tried to migrate the `sites` app separately with `python manage.py migrate sites` but that fails with: `CommandError: App 'sites' does not have migrations`.

Do you have any idea on way resolve this?

Installed Apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ( 
  'django.contrib.sites',
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  'users',
  'django.contrib.admin',
)
```

Migration error:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, users, auth, sessions
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
update build with example
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying users.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test-project/manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/conti/dev/test-project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/conti/dev/test-project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 342, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/conti/dev/test-project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/conti/dev/test-project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/conti/dev/test-project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    emit_post_migrate_signal(self.verbosity, self.interactive, connection.alias)
  File "/Users/conti/dev/test-project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 50, in emit_post_migrate_signal
    using=db)
  File "/Users/conti/dev/test-project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 192, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
build without jspm for travis team
  File "/Users/conti/dev/test-project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/management.py", line 20, in create_default_site
    if not Site.objects.using(using).exists():
  File "/Users/conti/dev/test-project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 651, in exists
    return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
  File "/Users/conti/dev/test-project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 501, in has_results
    return compiler.has_results()
  File "/Users/conti/dev/test-project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 823, in has_results
    return bool(self.execute_sql(SINGLE))
  File "/Users/conti/dev/test-project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 852, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/conti/dev/test-project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/conti/dev/test-project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/conti/dev/test-project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/conti/dev/test-project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_site" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "django_site" LIMIT 1
                               ^
```

Comment: `return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)` what is the sql? params?

Comment: @AviahLaor the values are [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sites/management.py#L28). That comes from `django/db/backends/utils.py` kicked off by django sites post migration hook which uses the `create_default_site` management command to pass in the values.  What are you looking for? To my knowlege, theres not a meaningful way that I can affect the `create_default_site` command without patching django's source.

Comment: It seems like a DB error. I would test the sql directly in the DB, see what's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by removing the sites migration from my settings:

```
MIGRATION_MODULES = {       
    'sites': 'contrib.sites.migrations'         
}
```

Comment: But did you add them afterwards? or did you just kill that functionality?